# read xml file using springsource springmvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, xml-parsing, xmlreader, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to read a xml file and parse it using Spring MVC, but for some reason it's not finding the file path. I tried different folder, even root, but still cant read or find the file in my project. I'm also using a bean and its not working ether.

```
<bean class="com.fdm.routePlanner.data.LineDataReader">
    <property name="file">
    <value>/resources/CompleteTube.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and

```
SAXBuilder saxbuilder = new SAXBuilder();
 try {
    return generateNetwork( saxbuilder.build(new File(file)) );
  } catch (JDOMException e) {
```

When I try to parse the file using `SAXBuilder` it gives me a NullPointerException.

Comment: To which line exactly points this NullPointerException?

Comment: this line return generateNetwork( saxbuilder.build(new File(file)) );

Comment: This means `file` is null - are you sure there's setFile(String file) method inside `LineDataReader`?

Comment: yes i have a setFile, i beleive that its not finding the path or i may be wrong

Comment: In debug, is `file` properly set?